# Where can I find the lib directory of ant after installing ant via apt-install in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ant

I have to install ant with ant-contrib. I had installed Apache ant in Ubuntu 18.04. Now to use ant-contrib ,I have to add the jar file into the lib directory. But after installing ant where do I find its lib directory. I have tried the which ant command, it shows usr/local/ant. When I went to that location, I found only a file named ant and no directory. I have no previous knowledge of ant. Where will I find the directory?